# Spark nested loop and RDD transformations

Tags: pyspark

I am looking for example code that implements a nested loop in spark. I am looking for the following functionality.

Given a RDD `data1 = sc.parallelize(range(10))` and another dataset `data2 = sc.parallelize(['a', 'b', 'c'])`, I am looking for something which will pick each 'key' from `data2`, append each 'value' from `data1` to create a list of key value pairs that look, perhaps in internal memory, something like `[(a,1), (a, 2), (a, 3), ..., (c, 8), (c, 9)]` and then do a reduce by key using a simple reducer function, say `lambda x, y: x+y`.

From the logic described above, the expected output is

```
(a, 45)
(b, 45)
(c, 45)
```

#### My attempt

```
data1 = sc.parallelize(range(100))
data2 = sc.parallelize(['a', 'b', 'c'])
f = lambda x: data2.map(lambda y: (y, x))
data1.map(f).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y)
```

#### The obtained error

```
Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or
reference an RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations 
and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other 
transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() * x) 
is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be 
performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, 
see SPARK-5063.
```

I am a complete newbie this, so any help is highly appreciated!

#### OS Information

I am running this on a standalone spark installation on linux. Details available if relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential solution. I am not too happy with it, though, because it doesn't represent a true for loop.

```
data1 = sc.parallelize(range(10))
data2 = sc.parallelize(['a', 'b', 'c'])
data2.cartesian(data1).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y).collect()
```

gives

```
[('a', 45), ('c', 45), ('b', 45)]
```